# In "The Final Empire", why does Clubs not stay in the initial meeting?

Tags: cosmere, mistborn, the-final-empire

In The Final Empire, book 1 of Brandon Sanderson's Mistborn trilogy, the crew have an initial meeting to decide who's "in". Part-way through this meeting, Clubs storms out, only to return later and speak to Kelsier alone. He cites his reason as not trusting Breeze with his Soothing ability. Yet Clubs would be immune to these effects, as he is a Smoker. So, why did he leave the initial meeting?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Clubs states a few different times that it's not just Soothing that he doesn't trust about Soothers. He feels that Soothers are constantly manipulating people, even when they aren't using Allomancy. He has a great conversation with Breeze in The Well of Ascension on this topic.

Comment: Dang it, you beat me to it - I _thought_ that was the answer, but I needed to double check the book :)

Answer (score 5):

Adam's answer is correct, but in fact the conversation between Clubs and Breeze in *The Well of Ascension* specifically addresses the reason why Clubs left the initial meeting:

> Breeze smiled. Clubs was one of the few people who was completely immune to his touch. Emotional Allomancy wouldn't work on him, and he was always completely forthcoming with his emotions: everything made him grumpy. Manipulating him through non-Allomantic means had proven to be a fruitless waste of time.
>
> Breeze regarded his wine. "The amusing thing is, you almost didn't join the crew because of me."
>
> "Dang Soothers," Clubs muttered.
>
> "But you're immune to us."
>
> "To your Allomancy, maybe," Clubs said. "But that isn't the only way you people do things. A man always has to watch himself around Soothers."
>
> <sub>-- *The Well of Ascension*, Chapter 36, p.429</sub>